# source for package to install via chef

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

I am installing few rpms using chef recipes, the problem is source for rpm's as I can't put them in yum repository. Can I use chef server as a source for rpm's ? how do I specify the source in recipe in that case.
somehow there is no detailed info on opscode for what options are available for source...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting the [package documentation](https://docs.chef.io/resource_package.html#properties)

> `source`   Ruby Type: String
>
> Optional. The path to a package in the local file system.

So the best idea is using [`remote_file`](https://docs.chef.io/resource_remote_file.html) and [`package`](https://docs.chef.io/resource_package.html) with something like this:

```
remote_file '/usr/local/src/my_package.rpm' do
  source 'http://any_internal_web_server/path/my_package.rpm'
end

package 'my_package.rpm' do
  source '/usr/local/src/my_package.rpm'
end
```

You may also use [`cookbook_file`](https://docs.chef.io/resource_cookbook_file.html) and put your package into the cookbook, but it's usually advised to avoid storing large binary files in VCS (svn, git, mercurial, other). Further, it would be stored on the Chef Server then, too.

Comment: I was just avoiding to copy it local on all servers..is there a way to just find it on chef server and install..thanks

Comment: If you want to avoid copy on all the server, you can't. Even using a yum repository, yum will download the package before installing it...

Comment: I agree with Tensibai. Chef Server is a store for cookbooks, not for large binaries. You will run into trouble otherwise. Anyways, you have to download the file from somewhere to local disk and the Chef Server is definitely the wrong place.

Comment: @Tensibai I've made an [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/32378568/revisions) to your posting, hope this still reflects your opinion.

Comment: @StephenKing No problem. We may add it will consume the space twice on the target servers, as there will be a copy of the rpm in `/var/chef/cache/cookbook` and on the target of `cookbook_file`. (And I don't wish to enter in the tricky lazy load/get from cache things)